# Vue computed property do not send data to template

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a Login Page on which the user has to authorize and it is working.

Then the user is being redirected to the next page called `Dashboard` and I want to get his user profile details from the different endpoint, using Vuex.

I can see in the console, that data is retrieved immediately after the page is loaded, but it's not displayed on the page, I need to refresh the page to load the data. Can someone help me to figure out how to get rid of the page reload and put the data there automatically?

First, under `created()` I am using dispatch to get the data, and then in the computed present it.

Here is my code first `Dashbaord.vue` and `user.module.js`:

```js
import HeaderBar from "@/components/header/HeaderBar.vue";

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  components: { HeaderBar },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("user_account/getUserDetails");
    console.log("DASHBOARD: Created");
    console.log(this.$store.status);
  },
  computed: {
    currentUser() {
      console.log("Computed");
      console.log(this.$store.state);
      return this.$store.state.user_account;
    },
  },
};
```

```css
.dashboard {
  h4 {
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <main role="main">
      <div
        class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3"
      >
        <h1 class="h1">Hi, {{ currentUser.first_name }}</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            Search will be here added
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <div class="mt-4 mb-5">
      <HeaderBar />
    </div>

    <main role="main">
      <div class="row mb-2">
       
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import UserService from "../services/user.service";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
console.log("USER MODULE: ")
console.log(user)
const initialState = user
    ? user
    : null;
console.log(initialState)
export const user_account = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: initialState,
    actions: {
        async getUserDetails({commit}) {
            return UserService.getUserDetails().then(
                (user) => {
                    commit("getUserDetailsSuccess", user);
                    return Promise.resolve(user);
                },
                (error) => {
                    commit("getUserDetailsFailure");
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            );
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        getUserDetailsSuccess(state, user) {
            state.user = user;
        },
        getUserDetailsFailure(state) {
            state.user = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to initialize a state with `const initialState = user ? user : { user: null }`

Comment: In what place I should do it? I have it in my user.module.js already

Comment: I mean you should replace `const initialState = user ? user : null;` with `const initialState = user ? user : { user: null }`

Comment: Changing this line didn't work. I still need to refresh the page.

Comment: How does `user` look after it was saved to a local sotrage and retrieved from it?

Answer (score 0):

`user_account/getUserDetailsSuccess` sets `state.user`, but your computed prop does not return `.user`.

It should look like this:

```js
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('user_account/getUserDetails')
  },
  computed: {
    currentUser() {
      // return this.$store.state.user_account ❌
      return this.$store.state.user_account.user
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuex-modules-x5jsi?file=/src/components/Dashboard.vue:221-264)